# Writing my own shell in C

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I am first getting involved with the all the functions related to the shell. I already understood the concept of fork(), execvp and built-in functions; however, I don't know how to handle pipes and redirection operators. At first I thought that pipes and redirection operators were handled by execvp but it looks like they don't since they are not programs. Can u provide insight about writing shells in C concerning pipes and redirection operators?

Answer (score 2):

To implement *pipes* and *redirection* you need a mechanism to redefined the stdin and stdout of the binaries started by your shell. Once you wrap your head around that, everything else should be pretty straightforward  :-)

Good luck!

Comment: vote-up fully earned XD